# How do I read bool vars from a list, and move the "true" entries to another list

Tags: c#, winforms, list, arraylist, boolean

I'm looking to sort my entries into three different lists based on bool vars. Then I also need my list to not duplicate entries, so whatever entries are used, then need removed.

The list I'm using is here:

```
    public class Associate
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string AssocRfid { get; set; }
        public string AssocId { get; set; }
        public bool CanDoDiverts { get; set; }
        public bool CanDoMhe { get; set; }
        public bool CanDoLoading { get; set; }
    }
```

The code where this list is going to be read is here (not sure if it matters?).

```
                #region Dialog Yes

            case DialogResult.Yes:
                {
                var secondForm = new Form2();
                secondForm.Show();
                dataGridAssociates.Rows.Clear();
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileChosen); //Array of all the lines in the text file
                    foreach (var assocStringer in lines)
                    {
                        if (assocStringer == null) continue;
                        var entries = assocStringer.Split('|');
                        if (entries.Count() < 7)
                            return;
                        var obj = (Associate) _bindingSource.AddNew();
                        if (obj == null) continue;
                        obj.FirstName = entries[0];
                        obj.LastName = entries[1];
                        obj.AssocId = entries[2];
                        obj.AssocRfid = entries[3];
                        obj.CanDoDiverts = Convert.ToBoolean(entries[4]);
                        obj.CanDoMhe = Convert.ToBoolean(entries[5]);
                        obj.CanDoLoading = Convert.ToBoolean(entries[6]);
                    }
                break;
            }
                #endregion
```

Here is the list:

```
Matthew|Something|114282353|MXW320|True|True|True|
Audrey|Something|114282354|AXW420|True|True|True|
John|Doe|111222333|JXD020|True|True|False|
```

I need the whole line/entry to move to a separate list/container of some kind.

The _bindingSource is to add my code to a datagridview, it isn't important in this part of my code. Feel free to modify any part of this to make it work, I'm totally lost.

Also, my apologies for sloppy code, I'm still learning, any additional input on my code is welcomed.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? From the first part it sounds like a good candidate for LINQ, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: just use three `List` then?

Comment: Are you looking for this psuedocode: List of first CanDo, List of second CanDo, List of third CanDo, List of all that are not contained in the first three?

Comment: There are going to be three listboxes that the entries are going to be sorted into, I want the whole associate entry to be moved from the main list (that is generated from a text file) into the three separate listboxes. Honestly I'm not even sure if I'm using my list right. Would my list.txt be of any use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the bools as bools!

```
public class Associate
{
    ...
    public bool CanDoDiverts { get; set; }
    public bool CanDoMhe { get; set; }
    public bool CanDoLoading { get; set; }
}
```

Create three lists before the loop

```
var divertsList =  new List<Associate>();
var mheList =  new List<Associate>();
var loadingList =  new List<Associate>();
```

After having created and filled a new object (within the loop) add it to the lists like this

```
obj.FirstName = entries[0];
obj.LastName = entries[1];
obj.AssocId = entries[2];
obj.AssocRfid = entries[3];
obj.CanDoDiverts = Boolean.Parse(entries[4]);
obj.CanDoMhe = Boolean.Parse(entries[5]);
obj.CanDoLoading = Boolean.Parse(entries[6]);

if(obj.CanDoDiverts) {
    divertsList.Add(obj);
}
if(obj.CanDoMhe) {
    mheList.Add(obj);
}
if(obj.CanDoLoading) {
    loadingList.Add(obj);
}
```

---

You could also append all the associates to the same list and filter the list as needed

```
var canDoDivertsQuery = associatesList.Where(a => a.CanDoDiverts);
foreach (Associate associate in canDoDivertsQuery) {
    // Work with associate being able to do diverts
}
```

Comment: Will this pull the whole associate entry into the list?

Comment: Every call to `list.Add(obj)` adds an associate to the list.

Comment: Ended up using LINQ, because I needed to randomize my master associate list. Used GUIDs on each entry, then used LINQ to populate the three lists. If you're interested in seeing my final solution let me know and I can post it up. One thing I hated doing though was using "goto"s in my code, I wasn't sure how to avoid that...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want correctly.

Use a linq query to pull out the results you want. You can then remove the items from the original list.

```
 var associates = new List<Associate> 
 { 
      new Associate{CanDoDiverts = true}, 
      new Associate{CanDoDiverts = false}
 };

 var resultList = associates.Where(p => p.CanDoDiverts == true).ToList();
 // .ToList() ensures deferred execution wont result in the ResultList being empty when you remove the matching items from the master list.
 associates.RemoveAll(p => p.CanDoDiverts == true);
```

By the way  your properties should be booleans and not strings if you are testing for booleans

Comment: I will definitely move the CanDo vars to bool.